# Ansible stdout_callback log_plays using same format as normal playbook stdout

Tags: ansible

I've set the following into my ansible.cfg [defauls] section:

```
callback_whitelist = log_plays yaml
stdout_callback = log_plays
```

And everything is fine since it writes the output to /var/log/ansible/hosts/{nodename}

The problem is the output format. It's a full json dump from the ansible data; I would love to see the same format as I see when I push an ansible-playbook. The log_plays is not configurable.

Is it even possible without programming another callback in python (or modifying the one created)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the answer of you want but maybe it could help you.

Create an executable file `logging.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

export ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH=/home/user/ansibleLogs/playbook_$(echo $1 | cut -d . -f 1)_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).log
ansible-playbook $@
```

Add this line in your `.bashrc` file

`alias ansible-playbook="/path/to/logging.sh"`

Execute

`source /home/user/.bashrc`

Then when you execute a playbook this will create a log for that execution, for example

```
ansible-playbook test.yml
```

This create the file `playbook_test_20201111203726.log` in the path `/home/user/ansibleLogs`.

```yaml
    2020-11-11 20:37:26,988 p=1829212 u=glopez n=ansible | PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************
    2020-11-11 20:37:27,004 p=1829212 u=glopez n=ansible | TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************
    2020-11-11 20:37:27,039 p=1829212 u=glopez n=ansible | ok: [localhost] => {
        "msg": "/home/glopez/Downloads/playbook_test_20201111203726.log"
    }
    2020-11-11 20:37:27,042 p=1829212 u=glopez n=ansible | TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************************************
    2020-11-11 20:37:27,083 p=1829212 u=glopez n=ansible | ok: [localhost]
    2020-11-11 20:37:27,089 p=1829212 u=glopez n=ansible | TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************
    2020-11-11 20:37:27,143 p=1829212 u=glopez n=ansible | ok: [localhost] => {
        "Test": []
    }
    2020-11-11 20:37:27,151 p=1829212 u=glopez n=ansible | PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************
    2020-11-11 20:37:27,151 p=1829212 u=glopez n=ansible | localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```